# Jetpack Compose Animation Not Starting

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using `animateIntAsState` for rounding some TextField but animation not starting after changing animation state.

this is my code

```
val animateCornerState = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    
val animateCorner = animateIntAsState(
    targetValue = if (animateCornerState.value) 50 else 0,
    animationSpec = tween(
        delayMillis = 700,
        durationMillis = 1000
    )
)
    
Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
) {
    repeat(4) { index ->
        TextField(
            value = token.getOrNull(index) ?: "",
            onValueChange = { viewModel.setCurrentToken(it) },
            singleLine = true,
            maxLines = 1,
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(64.dp)
                .height(64.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(percent = animateCorner.value)),
        )
    }
}

if (!animateCornerState.value) {
    animateCornerState.value = true
}
```

There is one point that when I change `animateCornerState.value` in a LaunchEffect with some coroutine delay I work's But I think this should not done via this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#simple-example) mentions a list of properties which all composable functions should be written with. One of these is:

> The function describes the UI without any side-effects, such as modifying properties or global variables.

So, to make your composable side-effect free, [you should use the Effect APIs so that those side effects are executed in a predictable manner](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#:%7E:text=you%20should%20use%20the%20Effect%20APIs%20so%20that%20those%20side%20effects%20are%20executed%20in%20a%20predictable%20manner.).

You can do:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    if (!animateCornerState.value) {
        animateCornerState.value = true
    }
}
```